# for in loop affecting only last element of array,I want my code to work on each element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to change html of each class that is contained in my array. But for(var i in array) loop only processing the last array element.How to make it work for each element of array.Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = [],
        array = [".1", ".2", ".3", ".4", ".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"];
    // a.push($(array[i]).html());
    for (var i in array) {
        $(array[i]).click(function() {
            $(array[i]).html(0);
        });
    }
});
```

See the problem here http://codepen.io/meow414/pen/rLJaPJ (its code may change as I will be trying to solve it). HTML code is here :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="1 col-xs-4 col-md-4">1</div>
                <div class="2 col-xs-4 col-md-4">2</div>
                <div class="3 col-xs-4 col-md-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">4</div>
                <div class="5 col-xs-4 col-md-4">5</div>
                <div class="6 col-xs-4 col-md-4">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="7 col-xs-4 col-md-4">7</div>
                <div class="8 col-xs-4 col-md-4">8</div>
                <div class="9 col-xs-4 col-md-4">9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, a single number isn't a valid class selector. jQuery handles it, but it defaults to its non-standard, slower selector engine.

Comment: Explanation [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: There should be a special tag in SO `closures-in-loops`. The same mistake over and over. [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)

Comment: The problem is that the variable `i`, within each of the anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function... See my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `for` loop and crate a selector from your array using `join()`

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

  var array=[".1",".2",".3",".4",".5",".6",".7",".8",".9"];

  $(array.join(",")).click(function(){
     $(this).html("Hello");
  });

});
```

Currently you have an array

```
[".1",".2",".3",".4",".5",".6",".7",".8",".9"]
```

but you need a selector

```
".1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9"
```

therefore use `.join(",")`

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){
  
  var array=[".1",".2",".3",".4",".5",".6",".7",".8",".9"];


  $(array.join(",")).click(function(){
     $(this).html("Hello");
  });

  
});
```

```css
[class^=col-]{background:#eee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="1 col-xs-4 col-md-4">1
        </div>
        <div class="2 col-xs-4 col-md-4">2
        </div>
        <div class="3 col-xs-4 col-md-4">3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">4
        </div>
        <div class="5 col-xs-4 col-md-4">5
        </div>
        <div class="6 col-xs-4 col-md-4">6
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="7 col-xs-4 col-md-4">7
        </div>
        <div class="8 col-xs-4 col-md-4">8
        </div>
        <div class="9 col-xs-4 col-md-4">9
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that using Number as class is invalid. Will work in JS bul will fail in CSS. (P.S: ID as Number on the other hand is valid in HTML5)

Comment: If I do it,then all elements will be processed by for in loop?

Comment: @UzmaKhan remove the for loop. See my edit.

Comment: No need to use `array.join()`  because the problem is that the variable i, within each of the anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function... See my solution

Comment: @YosvelQuintero no need to use `for` loop at all. `$()` is already a collection of elements. See my solution.

Comment: The easiest and fast way: `$('.col-md-4').on('click', function() {$(this).html(0)});`

Comment: Yes, but not in the case where i.e: you're building an array of specific selectors like i.e: `[".1",".8","#foo"]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable `i`, within each of the anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function.

You can use the `this` reference in the event handler function:

```js
var array = [".1", ".2", ".3", ".4", ".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"];

for (var i in array) {
    $(array[i]).on('click', function() {
        $(this).html(0);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="1 col-xs-4 col-md-4">1</div>
                <div class="2 col-xs-4 col-md-4">2</div>
                <div class="3 col-xs-4 col-md-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4 col-xs-4 col-md-4">4</div>
                <div class="5 col-xs-4 col-md-4">5</div>
                <div class="6 col-xs-4 col-md-4">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="7 col-xs-4 col-md-4">7</div>
                <div class="8 col-xs-4 col-md-4">8</div>
                <div class="9 col-xs-4 col-md-4">9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the easiest and fast way according to your html is:

```
$('.col-md-4').click(function() {
    $(this).html(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach(); worked better. Solution:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var a=[],array=[".1",".2",".3",".4",".5",".6",".7",".8",".9"];
   // a.push($(array[i]).html());
  array.forEach(function(i){ $(i).click(function(){
    $(i).html(0);
   });
   }
   );

  });
```

Or

```
for(var i in array){
  $(array[i]).click(function(){
    $(this).html(0); //this to take current instance
   });
   }
```